# Asymptotic growth of products of powers of primes vs factorials

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, factorial

Suppose we are comparing products of powers of primes p vs. n!:

`p₁^(2n/p₁)∙p₂^(2n/p₂)∙p₃^(2n/p₃)∙p₄^(2n/p₄)∙...` vs. `n!`

If `p₁ = 2`, and `p₂ = 3`, then the right-hand-side (RHS) > left-hand-side (LHS) above a certain `n`

If `p₁ = 2`, `p₂ = 3`, and `5 ≤ p₃ ≤ 17`, then the LHS > RHS for all `n`

But for `p₁ = 2`, `p₂ = 3`, and `p₃ ≥ 19`, then again the RHS > LHS above a certain `n`

Right now I'm using Wolfram Alpha to investigate these combinations.

Wondering if there is a deterministic way to decide if these products of powers of primes is asymptotically less than or greater than `n!`?

Comment: Try to take log and use Stirling's formula for the RHS. RHS will have main term nlog(n), while LHS is a constant depending on $p_i$'s times n. So RHS>LHS eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using all the primes not greater than $n$ then $p_1^{\frac{2n}{p_1}}\cdots p_k^{\frac{2n}{p_k}}$ should be greater than $n!$.
We know that $n!$ is equal to $\prod p_i^{[\frac{n}{p_i}]+[\frac{n}{p_i^2}]+...}$
($[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$). So we only have to compare the exponents.

The exponent of every prime in the factorial is not greater than $\frac{n}{p_i-1}$.
But $\frac{n}{p_i-1}\leq \frac{2n}{p_i}$  for every $p\geq 2$
I do not understand why you find that RHS > LHS

Comment: Not using all the primes, picking and choosing `p₁`, `p₂`, `p₃`, etc.